# How do we custom Mahout's FileDataModel delimiterPattern?

Tags: java, mahout

I'm new to Mahout, and I'm using `FileDataModel`, but I found the delimiterPattern can't be overwritten, this is really wired, I think a well designed framework should consider different use cases.

```
private final Splitter delimiterPattern;
```

In my case, I want to change it to :

```
private final Splitter delimiterPattern = Splitter.onPattern("\\s+");
```

I have two question about this:

1. Why doesn't Mahout allow developers overwritten its delimiterPattern ?
2. How do we change it anyway ?

#### === UPDATE ===

It doesn't matter anymore, I just submit a patch(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1398) to Mahout, will be integrated in 0.9 release.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform some pre-processing and replace your given delimiter and make it a CSV file or something that you can use with mahout's FileDataModel.